# Extract Files from Jar file in Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a java applet that contains resources directory (Directory name is: Resources) this directory contains some dll files. (This directory/folder is packaged in the jar file for the applet).

I am trying to extract the contents of this directory to the local hard disk.
I am using

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Resources/" + fileName);
```

to get the file and save it to another path so i can access it.
This method is working before deploying/embedding my applet to a HTML page.

I Have two problems:

1- After deploying on a web server, this method returns null.

2- How to enumerate all files in the resources folder after deploying my applet, so that i can save these files to another path.

Sorry if my question is stupid, simple or unclear because this is the first Java applet for me.

Comment: You can't list a directory in side a Jar (technically it doesn't have any). What I tend to is, during the build process, I create a known file which contains a list of all the resources within in the directory. At runtime, I load this file and the use its contents to find all the other resources

Comment: i think about this solution, but i said there must be a better solution

Comment: Well, unless you know the jar file and can reference it from your program, you can't list resources

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting an alternative for your second question. You could run OS commands in your java code to do these operations. If you are on a linux environment to extract the whole folder and copy somewhere else you can run

```
jar xf yourjarfile.jar Resources
cp -rf Resources toSomewhereElse/
```

in your java code. You can find examples [here](https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/) to see how to run OS commands in your Java code.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i run on Windows and also i don't know what is the path of the jar file on the client machine